# Trigger Speech Recognition in Android Service

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech, speech

I have been trying to find a way to implement the SpeechRecognizer API in a Service (runs in background) so that when a condition is met, it will open the speech recognizer without having to be within the application. My question is whether this is even possible natively? And if so, how would it be done?

Comment: what you have done so far? And its not a good idea to run SpeechRecognizer in the background because it consumes too much battery and internet and other resources.

Comment: I wont be running it in the background, it will be triggered when a condition is met.

Comment: Have you known to SpeechRecognizer with custom listener instead of Google Prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my code snippet. You can use the recognition listener like this in a service.
I'm not sure how you are scheduling your services, I have left that to you. But you can do something like this. (I have not added code for restarting service / starting it in a timer etc.)

```
    public class MyService extends Service {
    protected static SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer;
    protected Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent;
    Context c;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //if condition is met then do this
        SpeechRecognitionListener h = new SpeechRecognitionListener();
        mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
        mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(h);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        Log.d("avail", " " + mSpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(this));
        if (mSpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(this))
            Log.d("created", "onBeginingOfSpeech");
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
                this.getPackageName());
        mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);

        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        c= getApplicationContext();


    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }



    class SpeechRecognitionListener implements RecognitionListener {

        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle bundle) {

            Log.d("onReady", "service");
        }

        @Override
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float v) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] bytes) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEndOfSpeech() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int i) {
            Log.d("ERROR","ERROR");
        }

        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle resultsBundle) {
            Log.d("Results", "onResults"); 
        }

        @Override
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks heaps

Comment: No probs. Cheers!